# $I_n:=\int_1^n\ln(t)dt$, $u_n:=\ln(n!)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)$, $L:=\lim_{x\to \infty}(I_n-u_n)$, $c=1-L$. Show that $n!~\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$I_n:=\int_1^n\ln(t)dt$

$u_n:=\ln(n!)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)$

$L:=\lim_{n\to \infty}(I_n-u_n)$

Show that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}
n!~\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^{1-L}$$

Note that $a_n\approx b_n$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$.

I already know that
$$ 0\le I_n-u_n\le\frac{1}{4}(1-\frac{1}{n}) \tag1$$
and sequence  $(I_n-u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing.
And by $(1)$, can know that
$$\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^{1-L} ~\le~ n! ~\le~ \frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne$$
let $c=1-L$. But

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}\le\frac{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne}{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}=e^L.$$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\frac{n!}{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}$$\ge$$\frac{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}$=1.
Thus 1$\le$$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\frac{n!}{\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^c}$$\le$e$^L$$\neq1$.
Hence can't prove n!~$\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^1$$^-$$^L$.
Are there something wrong in process, or a better way to prove n!~$\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt ne^1$$^-$$^L$?
And moreover, how to use Wallis Product to prove e$^1$$^-$$^L$=$\sqrt(2\pi)$.
Then we can find out n!~$\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt(2n\pi)$.

Comment: wikipedia has a derivation for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Actually... I couldn't understand the process on Wiki, that's why I came here to ask.

Answer (score 0):

0 $\le$ I$_n$-u$_n$ $\le$ $\frac{1}{4}$(1-$\frac{1}{n}$)
$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ (I$_n$-u$_n$)=L
$\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ (I$_n$-u$_n$-L)=0
$\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ exp(I$_n$-u$_n$-L)=1
$\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $\frac{exp(I_n)}{exp(u_n+L)}$=1
$\Rightarrow$ exp(I$_n$) ~ exp(u$_n$-L)
$\Rightarrow$ exp($\int_1^n$ln(t)dt) ~ exp(ln(n!)-$\frac{1}{2}$ln(n)+L)
$\Rightarrow$ exp(nln(n)-n+1) ~ n! $\cdot$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ $\cdot$ e$^L$
$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{n^n}{e^n}$$\sqrt n$e$^1$$^-$$^L$ ~ n!
Perhaps this is a better way to prove?